# Renvari is determined. What do I do?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the mission [Deeply Tangled Root](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Deeply_Tangled_Roots), one of the objectives is "Defeat the Nightmare courtiers." Problem is, Renvari has the [Determined](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Determined) buff and appears to be completely invulnerable.

What am I missing?

Comment: It says defeat the nightmare courtiers - maybe defeating Renvari is not a part of your task? I guess you'll have to deal with him being invulnerable while you defeat the others :S

Comment: @SadlyNot Sadly, not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a last pocket of courtier resistance on the side parallel to the main entrance to the quest zone, past the small bump straight ahead from the respawn point. It was marked with a second objective marker on my screen.

Once these foul men and all other are dealt with, Renvari loses his buff and becomes vulnerable.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into this issue also.